# Cron sessionclean errors: find: `/proc/xxxxx/fd': No such file or directory

Tags: php, session, cron, find

After PHP upgrade I started to get the following cron errors several times a day:

```
find: `/proc/xxxxx/fd': No such file or directory
```

It comes from PHP sessionclean cron job:

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine that is hosting this? ;) Also can you confirm the path of the `session.save_path` configuration?

Comment: sessionclean tries to update sessions for non existing php processes. Maybe you should restart the machine or at least restart apache to update php process information.

Comment: Restart doesn't help. Session save_path is set to: /var/lib/php5/sessions
These errors don't happen every time (sessionclean runs every 30 minutes and this errors appears sometimes several times a day, sometimes only once in several days).
In addition to this most scripts use custom session handler which means sessions folder is almost always empty

Comment: Check wheather you have permission or to create file also if possible set your own session.save_path like 
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));  then try

Answer (score 2):

There now is a Debian bug reported (and [fixed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827370)) about this.

It mentions about a release to stable:

> In the next security upload, e.g. roughly two weeks after 5.6.23 is
>   released, unless something else critical shows up.

5.6.23 is out, so I expect it within the next two weeks.

The fix there is to add

```
if [ -d "/proc/$pid/fd" ]; then
```

before the

```
find "/proc/$pid/fd"
```

command.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore those errors, the `sessionclean` search for session attached to a no longer existing pid.

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean 2>/dev/null
```

You should look inside your session directory to check that they are correctly cleaned because such message might be symptomatic of a too long processing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I prefer not to suppress these errors to be notified if something is wrong with the script.
sessions folder is cleaned correctly and almost always it's empty since most of the scripts use custom session handler. I checked the contents of the folder - it holds current session files and usually has just a couple of files if any.
I wonder what is the real cause of this problem and how to solve it (instead of suppressing the error)...

Comment: There is nothing wrong : the process has finished during the execution of the sessionclean script. If you don't want to suppress any other error, then you have to modify the script.

Comment: @Adam I'm getting this problem, too, but don't know what to think of it. In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini I don't have a `save_path`, but in /var/lib/php5/sessions there are 2 session files dated from a couple of hours ago. I think they should be there, but I don't know how to be sure. Also, the xxxx in `/proc/xxxx/fd` are consistently for active apache2 processes. I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to eliminate the errors, although, all bets are off as to whether you are eliminating a problem or just masking it. I have several containers running, and some have this problem while others don't.

The /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean that will generate the error is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

SAPIS="apache2:apache2\napache2filter:apache2\ncgi:php5\nfpm:php5-fpm\n"

# Iterate through all web SAPIs
(
printf "$SAPIS" | { \
proc_names=""
while IFS=: read -r conf_dir proc_name; do
    if [ -e /etc/php5/${conf_dir}/php.ini ]; then
        # Get all session variables once so we don't need to start PHP to get each config option
        session_config=$(php5 -c /etc/php5/${conf_dir}/php.ini -d "error_reporting='~E_ALL'" -r 'foreach(ini_get_all("session") as $k => $v) echo "$k=".$v["local_value"]."\n";')
        save_handler=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_handler=\(.*\)$/\1/p')
        save_path=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_path=\(.*\)$/\1/p')
        gc_maxlifetime=$(($(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.gc_maxlifetime=\(.*\)$/\1/p')/60))

        if [ "$save_handler" = "files" -a -d "$save_path" ]; then
            proc_names="$proc_names $proc_name";
            printf "%s:%s\n" "$save_path" "$gc_maxlifetime"
        fi
    fi
done
# first find all open session files and touch them (hope it's not massive amount of files)
for pid in $(pidof $proc_names); do
    find "/proc/$pid/fd" -ignore_readdir_race -lname "$save_path/sess_\*" -exec touch -c {} \;
done
} ) | sort -rn -t: -k2,2 | sort -u -t: -k 1,1 | while IFS=: read -r save_path gc_maxlifetime; do
    # find all files older then maxlifetime and delete them
    find -O3 "$save_path" -depth -mindepth 1 -name 'sess_*' -ignore_readdir_race -type f -cmin "+$gc_maxlifetime" -delete
done

exit 0
```

But if I replace that w/a /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean from a container that doesn't generate the error, which is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

SAPIS="apache2:apache2\napache2filter:apache2\ncgi:php5\nfpm:php5-fpm\n"

# Iterate through all web SAPIs
(
proc_names=""
printf "$SAPIS" | \
while IFS=: read -r conf_dir proc_name; do
    if [ -e /etc/php5/${conf_dir}/php.ini ]; then
        # Get all session variables once so we don't need to start PHP to get each config option
        session_config=$(php5 -c /etc/php5/${conf_dir}/php.ini -d "error_reporting='~E_ALL'" -r 'foreach(ini_get_all("session") as $k => $v) echo "$k=".$v["local_value"]."\n";')
        save_handler=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_handler=\(.*\)$/\1/p')
        save_path=$(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.save_path=\(.*\)$/\1/p')
        gc_maxlifetime=$(($(echo "$session_config" | sed -ne 's/^session\.gc_maxlifetime=\(.*\)$/\1/p')/60))

        if [ "$save_handler" = "files" -a -d "$save_path" ]; then
            proc_names="$proc_names $proc_name";
            printf "%s:%s\n" "$save_path" "$gc_maxlifetime"
        fi
    fi
done
# first find all open session files and touch them (hope it's not massive amount of files)
for pid in $(pidof $proc_names); do
    find "/proc/$pid/fd" -ignore_readdir_race -lname "$save_path/sess_\*" -exec touch -c {} \;
done
) | sort -rn -t: -k2,2 | sort -u -t: -k 1,1 | while IFS=: read -r save_path gc_maxlifetime; do
    # find all files older then maxlifetime and delete them
    find -O3 "$save_path" -depth -mindepth 1 -name 'sess_*' -ignore_readdir_race -type f -cmin "+$gc_maxlifetime" -delete
done

exit 0
```

Then I don't get the errors.